# How to test com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status#hasResolution & startResolutionForResult?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin

I'm using Google Sign-In to [Authenticate with a backend server](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth), and want to test if I'm using [Status#hasResolution](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/Status#hasResolution()) and [Status#startResolutionForResult](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/Status#startResolutionForResult(android.app.Activity,%20int)) correctly, but I don't know how to trigger the code path where hasResolution is true and startResolutionForResult launches an activity.

The Status is coming from [GoogleSignInResult#getStatus()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInResult#getStatus()) and the GoogleSignInResult is acquired with code like [this sample](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth#send-the-id-token-to-your-server).

Does anyone know an easy way (manually) test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open you phone's Settings app > apps > `Google Play Services` > Menu > "Uninstall Updates".

you might then need to click on the "DISABLE" button to disable to factory-installed version of it.

You'll now probably start seeing lots of error notifications from several apps (Gmail, Drive, etc.) about not being able to find `Google Play Services`.

You should also get your `onConnectionFailed` in your app, with an intent to update `Play Services`.

Comment: At the moment I get a `ConnectionResult` with `hasResolution()` returning `false` when Google Play Services is Disabled or requires an update. This means I show the Google error dialog which contains the action to launch the `Intent` to either enable or update the app. Do you know another way to get `hasResolution()` to be `true`?

Comment: you *are* showing the dialog with the intent? then that means hasResolution returned true (otherwise there would be no action to perform).
I think that hasResolution should return true if there's an update to GPS, and you have Play installed and working with active internet connection.

Comment: `hasResolution()` actually returns `false`, the behaviour must have changed, however I discovered that I can use `GoogleApiAvailability` to get the `Intent` for an error code. It supports `SERVICE_MISSING`, `SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED` and `SERVICE_DISABLED`. This enables me to display the error inline with a button to resolve, and fall back to showing the Google error dialog for any other error codes.